# how to integrate a jsfiddle into my webpage

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use the following jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/karanmhatre/9tny5eh6/6/

in my website but cant seem to get it to work. I know this topic is discussed extensively and I've spent the entire day trying to figure this out but just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm a newbie and could really use some help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drag and Drop Video</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'>     </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".drag").draggable({
    revert: true,
    containment: "#content"
});
$(".drop").droppable(
{ 
      drop: function (event, ui) 
      {
          $(".drag").animate({
              top: "0px",
              left: "0px"
          });
         var url = $(ui.draggable).attr('videourl');
         var oggurl = $(ui.draggable).attr('oggurl');
         var $videocontainer = $('#video-container');

         $videocontainer.empty().append('<video id="video" controls width="400" height="300"><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+oggurl+'" type="video/ogg" /></video>');
         $('#video').get(0).play();
      }
});
});
}); // Closes window.load

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="thumbs">
    <img class="drag one-half" videourl="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" oggurl="profile-amanda.ogv" id="image" src="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/wp-content/themes/bunny/graphics/header1.jpg" />

    <img class="drag one-half last" videourl="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" oggurl="profile-amanda.ogv" id="image" src="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/wp-content/themes/bunny/graphics/header2.jpg" />
</div>

<br style="clear:both;" />

<div id="video-container" class="drop">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to describe what you mean by "cant seem to get it to work" - Related: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: You want to embed the actual jsFiddle page in your page, or you want to use the code from jsFiddle in your page? Also as a side note, you don't nee both `$(window).load(function(){` and `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that your code is loading jquery, but the fiddle loads both jQuery 1.9.1 AND **jQuery UI 1.9.2**

so try adding this line right after the line that loads jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```